# Thevenin Termination - Calculating \$I_{OH}\$

Tags: circuit-analysis, thevenin, termination

I am trying to see if my driver can drive the following circuit. The spec for the driver is \$V_{OH,min} = 1.62 V\$ and \$V_{OL,max} = 0.18 V\$ at \$I_{OH}/I_{OL} = +/-4 mA\$.

So the \$V_T = 0.9V\$ and I believe that max current needed when driver is high would be \$1.43 V/100 \Omega = 14.3 mA\$ which should be enough to satisfy the \$I_{OH}\$ spec. The receiver input impedance is very high in this circuit. Am I missing anything as I don't see a signal on the output?

Vdd is the same on both parts at 1.8V

[Driver Datasheet](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/371/SiT8924B_datasheet-1324430.pdf)

[Receiver Datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74auc2g80.pdf?ts=1711467481582&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FSN74AUC2G80%252Fpart-details%252FSN74AUC2G80DCTR)

Thanks!

[image: Thevenin Termination]

Comment: We need datasheets! Show us the transmitter and receiver models, and link to the datasheets. Also, tell us what you use for \$V_{DD}\$. Are you using the same voltage (not necessarily the same source, just same voltage) of \$V_{DD}\$ for both transmitter and receiver?

Comment: A very simple simulation would tell you the answer.

Comment: Is 50Ohm a transmission line? If it is is it grounded on the shield?

Comment: Its the impedance of the board trace